# Algorithm to insert string based on multiple regex rules

Tags: java, html, regex, algorithm, markdown

I am creating a Markdown-esque markup interface.
For example, when the user types in `**example string**`, regex is used to find the two occurrences of `**` (defining bold text), and the actual plaintext will be changed to `<b>**example string**</b>` and rendered as HTML.

This is my thinking for parsing the user's input into HTML:

1. For each rule in regex rules
2. For each occurrence of `start pattern` (of current regex rule)
3. Take all text *after* the end of `start pattern` (call this `start substring`)
4. For first instance of `end pattern` in `start substring`
5. Take `substring(start_match.start() + end_match.end())` from text
6. Append it to an initially blank `final text` string
7. Cull remaining text via `substring(start_match.start() + end_match.end())`, feed this back into the text read at **2.**

My code:

```
public static String process(String input_text) {
    String final_text = "";
    String current_text = input_text;

    for (MarkdownRule rule : _rules) {
        Pattern s_ptrn = rule.getStartPattern();    // Start pattern
        Pattern e_ptrn = rule.getEndPattern();      // End pattern

        /* For each occurrence of the start pattern */
        Matcher s_matcher = s_ptrn.matcher(current_text);
        while (s_matcher.find()) {
            int s_end = s_matcher.end();
            int s_start = s_matcher.start();

            /* Take all text after the end of start match */
            String working_text = current_text.substring(s_end); // ERROR HERE

            /* For first instance of end pattern in remaining text */
            Matcher e_matcher = e_ptrn.matcher(working_text);
            if (e_matcher.find()) {

                /* Take full substring from current text */
                int e_end = e_matcher.end();
                working_text = current_text.substring(s_start, s_end + e_end);

                /* Append to final text */
                working_text = new StringBuilder(working_text).insert(0, "<b>").append("</b>").toString();
                final_text = new StringBuilder(final_text).append(working_text).toString();

                /* Remove working text from current text */
                current_text = new StringBuilder(current_text).substring(s_start + e_end);
            }
        }
    }

    return final_text;
}
```

Although theoretically this should work fine, I'm getting a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` on this line:

```
/* Take all text after the end of start match */
String working_text = current_text.substring(s_end);
```

When I'm using the input text `**example**`. I believe it works fine for the first occurrence of `start pattern` (at indices 0 & 1), but then the string doesn't get culled properly and the loop is then called on the plaintext `**`, this giving the out of range error. (I can't guarantee this, though -- its just what I believe from my own testing)

Unfortunately, my troubleshooting could not remediate the error. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: why invent your own if there's already markdown?!?!

Comment: I want to manage it realtime, in a way similar to apps like Typora. Also just to see if I could!

Comment: not sure what realtime or not has to do with the syntax and parsers... but note that markdown parser writers have learned the hard way: basing your parser on regex is not a long-term strategy.. see https://github.com/jgm/CommonMark for a modern implementation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing (shrinking) `current_text`

```
/* Remove working text from current text */
current_text = new StringBuilder(current_text).substring(s_start + e_end);
```

while the matcher has stored the initial `current_text` string, which doesn't change, no matter what you do to `current_text` afterwards.

```
/* For each occurrence of the start pattern */
Matcher s_matcher = s_ptrn.matcher(current_text);
```

You need use a new matcher for the new string.

Comment: Ah - so `Matcher` caches the string value rather than referring to the instance. That's interesting (and a bit annoying). Thankyou!

Comment: That's not entirely correct. `Matcher` catches the **reference** to the `String` instance. Since `String` is an immutable object, you can't change the `String` value, but you can reference a **new** `String`. And that's what's happening when you are changing `current_text`. You're basically now referencing a **new** `String`, while `Matcher` is still referencing to the old `String`.